# Magento2 plugin/interceptor not working

Tags: magento2, plugin, interceptor

I have following action:

`http://localhost/admin/catalog/product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/135/key/…/`

I would like to do some extra things with attribute after saving.
I have created and registered custom plugin in `Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/Save.php` with following content:

```
class Save
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
     protected $config;


    /**
     * @param Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(Config $config, TypeListInterface $typeList)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Attribute $subject
     * @param Attribute $result
     * @return Attribute $result
     *
     */
    public function afterSave(Attribute $subject, Attribute $result)
    {
        # Do something
    }
}
```

I have also added following entry to `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute">
    <plugin name="do_stuff_after_attribute_save" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Save" />
</type>
```

But the plugin seems not to work. Even if I `die('somenthing');` or try to log to file, the code is not executed after saving the attribute.

Maybe I am trying to overwrite wrong method?

Comment: How can you create the plugin of `save` method when there is no `save` method in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

**You could follow the points below:**

1. You should use `di.xml` in the `adminhtml` folder as it is a backend issue.
2. You should override the `execute` method of this `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save` controller class.

**File:** `app/code/Milandev/Testplugin/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Milandev_Admin_Product_Attribute_Save" sortOrder="10" type="Milandev\Testplugin\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**File:** `app/code/Milandev/Testplugin/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Save.php`

```
<?php
namespace Milandev\Testplugin\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;

class Save
{

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        die('hello world!');
        //Your plugin code
    }
}
```